# Why did Kyurem stop showing up?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I was SR'ing for a shiny kyurem and he was showing up just fine. All of the sudden when I SRed it just said "A mysterious ring is floating in the air" and now I can't encounter him anymore. As far as I know there isn't a certain time of day that you have to catch him. Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: The only requirement is to have both Reshiram and Zekrom in your team, it's not time-based. That's weird, try deposit and withdraw them again. Have you changed the time on your 2/3DS?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. I have tried to depisit and withdraw both zekrom and rashiram but nothing happened and no I did not change the time on my 3ds because it was working when I first started to SR for kyurem. Maybe I need to be connected to the Internet for it to show up because it was about when I left my house when kyurem stopped showing up but I'm not certain.

Comment: Have you just SR'ed the last time? Maybe something went wrong, try beating the Elite Four again, I've read that it triggers the respawn of the legendaries.

Comment: Well I just started the game and kyurem is nowhere to be found. I went to see if I could catch dialga and I can. I will try to beat the elite 4 again but that might take some time because my team is barely a high enough level to be able to beat them.

Comment: Sorry if this is slightly noobish of me, but what's SR-ing?

Comment: @Cyberson [Soft resetting.](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Soft_resetting)

Comment: @jwodder how does one soft reset?

Comment: @Cyberson Follow the link in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

The game might think that you fled or made him faint, but it does not matter. All you have to is beat the elite four and champion and kyurem will reappear.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Beat the champion again and it should appear again.